# Ansible combine registered variable from multiple hosts

Tags: ansible

Good day,

I have the below task which adds two IPs to a subset (conditional include_tasks) of hosts in a play.

```
- name: Add two secondary private IPs to WSFC hosts 
  amazon.aws.ec2_eni:
    eni_id: '{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].network_interfaces[0].network_interface_id }}'
    secondary_private_ip_address_count: 2
    subnet_id: '{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].network_interfaces[0].subnet_id }}'
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: ec2_eni
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to create the below dictionary from `ec2_eni` containing all of the hosts the play was executed on. IPs should be sorted under each host.

```
some_dict:
  - hostname: host1
    ip1: ###.###.###.###
    ip2: ###.###.###.###
  - hostname: host2
    ip1: ###.###.###.###
    ip2: ###.###.###.###
```

`ec2_eni` looks like the below.

```
    "interface": {
        "id": "eni-999",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-999",
        "vpc_id": "vpc-999",
        "description": "Primary IPv4 interface for EC2 instance",
        "owner_id": "999",
        "status": "in-use",
        "mac_address": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
        "private_ip_address": "192.168.0.1",
        "source_dest_check": true,
        "groups": {
            "sg-999": "security-group"
        },
        "private_ip_addresses": [
            {
                "private_ip_address": "192.168.0.1",
                "primary_address": true
            },
            {
                "private_ip_address": "192.168.0.2",
                "primary_address": false
            },
            {
                "private_ip_address": "192.168.0.3",
                "primary_address": false
            }
        ]
    ...
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I need a combined dictionary of hosts and their secondary IPs from the registered variable on each host from the above task.

On a given host I can obtain the new private IPs with the below:


"ec2_eni.interface.private_ip_addresses | selectattr("primary_address", "equalto", false) | map(attribute="private_ip_address") | sort"


Obtaining a single combined dictionary like above has been the challenge. I nearly have a solution, but it's requiring a heavy dose of map extract, selectattr, and map attribute.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `ec2_eni` looks like/how it is structured?

Comment: @Rickkwa, updated per your question.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting it to work with the below, but I assume there is a better/cleaner way. In particular, how I had to combine the dictionaries from the two hosts seems messy.

```
- name: Create list of secondary private IPs that were provisioned
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    ec2_ips: '{{ ec2_eni.interface.private_ip_addresses | selectattr("primary_address", "equalto", false) | map(attribute="private_ip_address") | sort }}'

- name: Output secondary private IPs that were provisioned
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: 'Secondary private IPs: {{ ec2_ips }}'

- name: Create dictionary of hostname and one secondary private IP to be used as the WSFC virtual address
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    wsfc_cfg:
      hostname: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      cluster_ip: '{{ ec2_ips[0] }}'

- name: Combine two application server hostname/cluster_ip dictionaries into single dictionary
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    combined_wsfc_cfg: '{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map("extract", hostvars) | selectattr("wsfc_cfg", "defined") | map(attribute="wsfc_cfg") | list }}'
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but it feels like the loop `'{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map("extract", hostvars) | selectattr("wsfc_cfg", "defined") | map(attribute="wsfc_cfg") }}'` is already what you want? Like it is the same value as `combined_wsfc_cfg`. Just add `| list` filter after the `map` to convert it from generator to list.

Comment: @Rickkwa, you are correct. I was wrapped around the axle and overcomplicated that. 

Thank you.

Comment: I see that the `list` filter is typically applied after a `map` due to it being a generator. However, I accidentally left it off the above solution initially, and the results were the same. When/why is it really needed?

Comment: I'm probably used to an older version of ansible where you can't use generator for `loop`. Or some filters don't work on generator objects (like `| length`).

Comment: And I'd assume you get the normal python benefits of generators. Like reducing the memory footprint by not needing to load the entire list into memory.